# is it available to set up a server on amazon s3 with SpringWeb Framework?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I'm looking for the service that can use Spring Web Framework
Of course I could set up apache web server and tomcat.
However, I'm a new user of amazon web service.
is it available to set up a server with Spring Web Framework on Amazon web service?
What kind of services can be used ? ec2? s3?

Answer (score 0):

S3 is a service for storage of static content only, so you would need EC2 for that. You can provision an Ec2 instance (virtual private server) and set up your own tomcat and libraries (such as spring). Another way to go would be to use Elastic Beanstalk, that would automate the process of creating the infrastructure and you would only need to deploy your .war file.

A good resource to understand the services before starting would be the instructional videos and self paced labs you can find at http://aws.amazon.com/training/intro_series/